# String format and hex chars

Tags: c#, string, hex

can someone explain why this doesnt work:

```
string f = string.Format("\\x{0:00}{{0}}", 5);
string o = string.Format(f, "INSERT TEXT");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f + " : " + o);
```

Output is:

```
\x05{0} : \x05INSERT TEXT
```

why does the \x05 not get replaced?

Comment: Chars aren't hex or anything else, you want to output a char which corresponds to the value 5, also denoted as \x05. You should mark Mr. Listers answer as the correct one, since it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 10):

The format for the argument should be set in the format specifier, otherwise you're just inserting a literal "\x".  Like this:

```
// "5" as a lowercase 2-digit hex
string f = string.Format("{0:x2}{{0}}", 5);
```

Don't confuse how you represent a hex literal in source code with what you would print in a formatted string, they are different things.

Comment: but that would give me the string "05". I am trying to get the single hex character \x05 in the string but I cant put it in as a literal as it has to come from a variable (the example has hard coded 5, in reality is is int variable). Thats why i try to setup a format string separately first.

Comment: @user: How would you want it to be displayed?  When getting a number in it's hexadecimal form, you just get the digits, no "0x" prefixes.  If you wish to include those prefixes, you'd have to add that in yourself.

Answer (score 7):

To put a literal char in a string, just make sure that the compiler knows it's a char.

```
string f = string.Format("{0}", (char)5);
string g = string.Format("{0}", Convert.ToChar(5));
string h = string.Format("{0}", char.ConvertFromUtf32(5));
```

or you can start out with a real char:

```
string i = string.Format("{0}", '\x05');
string j = string.Format("{0}", '\u0005');
string k = string.Format("{0}", '\U00000005');
```

Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
  int x = 5;
  string f = string.Format("\\x{0:x2}{1}", x, "INSERT TEXT");
  Console.WriteLine(f);
```