# Covert string to hexdecimal string with format "\x..\x.."?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to convert a string with modified GUID (e.g. `6b5737e5728786794fff5e009d74d706`) to a hex string with format like `\x..\x..`

([String format and hex chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094139/string-format-and-hex-chars) doesn't work for me). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(myString, ".{2}", "\\x$0");
```

If you want to go a non-regex route, then the following might work:

```
string s = "6b5737e5728786794fff5e009d74d70";
var sb = new StringBuilder($s.Length * 2);

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i+=2)
  sb.Append("\\x").Append(s.Substring(i, [Math]::Min(2, s.Length - i)));

string myNewString = sb.ToString();
```

If you want your string to contain (for your example) the code points U+006B, U+0057, U+0037, &c. then think again please. *Strings are no byte containers, they are **text** containers.* You want a `byte[]` in that case:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[(s.Length + 1) / 2]
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i+=2)
  byteArray[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, [Math]::Min(2, s.Length - i)));
```

Comment: My string is a regular UTF8 string (with modified GUID) (e.g. 6b5737e5728786794fff5e009d74d706) and I need a hex string from it with specified format.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by UTF8 string. In .NET there is no such thing as all strings use UTF-16. And reiterating what your question already states doesn't really help if you don't tell me what exactly is wrong or problematic with my solution (which I think would work for your case).

Comment: "6b5737e5728786794fff5e009d74d70" is a string with UTF8 Encoding (Encoding.UTF8 for Windows Phone). I need to convert it to to the hexdecimal sting with "\x.." format.

Comment: There is no such thing as a string in UTF-8 encoding. Not even on Windows Phone. Besides, the encoding would be utterly irrelevant (usually, if we actually addressed strings by code point instead of code unit, but I doubt you'd have to handle astral planes) as strings represent *text*, not *bytes*.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are totally right, understood my task in a wrong way (thought I need code point). Sorry and thank you.